# Custom taxonomy terms in the admin site is not saving for widget

Tags: custom-taxonomy, widgets

I am using following codes to show the widget of next fixture.All data is showing correctly, but the custom taxonomy data (seasons and competition) are not saving in the admin site.When I am trying to save the data then it shows "all seasons" and "all competitions" instead desired season and competition.

Codes:

```
<?php
/**
 * Posts Widget
 *
 * @package Smart Blog
 * @since 1.0
 */

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'themepixels_register_widget_posts' );
function themepixels_register_widget_posts() {
    register_widget( 'themepixels_widget_posts' );
}

class themepixels_widget_posts extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'posts_widget', 'description' => __( 'Fixture', 'themepixels' ) );
        parent::__construct( 'themepixels_posts', __( 'Football Fixture', 'themepixels' ), $widget_ops );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        $seasons    = $instance['seasons']; 
        $competitions   = $instance['competitions']; 
        $posts_order_by = $instance['posts_order_by'];
        $posts_time_range = $instance['posts_time_range'];
        $post_count = intval( $instance['post_count'] );

        echo $before_widget;
        if( $title ) {
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        }

        $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'football_fixture',
            'posts_per_page'        => $post_count,
            'orderby'               => $posts_order_by,
            'order'                 => 'DESC',
            'meta_query'            => array(
                                         array(
                                          'key'     => 'pb_match_status',
                                          'value'   => 'fixture'
                                        ),
            ),
        );

        $fixture_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

        <?php   while ($fixture_query->have_posts()) : $fixture_query->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="competition-result clearfix" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <?php
          $id     = get_the_ID();
          $date     = rwmb_meta( 'pb_match_date','', $post->ID);
          $time     = rwmb_meta( 'pb_match_time','', $post->ID );
          $team_home  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),  'match_details_home_team', true );
          $team_away  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),  'match_details_away_team', true );
          $team_home_score  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'pb_home_score', true );
          $team_away_score  = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pb_away_score', true );
        ?>

        <div class="widget-fixture-details">  
          <aside class="widget-competition-home-team-name-left">
            <a href="<?php echo get_link_football_team( $team_home ); ?>"><?php echo $team_home; ?></a>
          </aside>
          <aside class="widget-competition-team-logo-and-time">
              <button type="button" class="btn match-time-button">
              <span>
              <?php 
                  if ( $team_home_score ) { 
                     echo $team_home_score;  
                  }
              ?>
              </span>-
               <span>
              <?php 
                  if ( $team_away_score ) { 
                     echo $team_away_score;  
                  }
              ?>
              </span>

               </button>
          </aside>
          <aside class="widget-competition-home-team-name-right">
            <a href="<?php echo get_link_football_team( $team_away ); ?>"><?php echo $team_away; ?></a>
          </aside>
          <aside class="widget-football-match-centre-details">
           <div class="football-match-details" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click for details">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>  
      </div><!--End post-->  

  <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php echo $after_widget; 
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['seasons'] = $new_instance['seasons'];
        $instance['competitions'] = $new_instance['competitions'];
        $instance['posts_order_by'] = $new_instance['posts_order_by'];
        $instance['post_count'] = $new_instance['post_count'];


        return $instance;
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        $defaults =  array(
            'title'                 => '',
            'taxonomy'              => '0',
            'meta_key'              => 'pb_match_date',
            'posts_order_by'        => 'meta_value',
            'post_count'            => 5,

        );

        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'themepixels' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['title'] ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'competitions' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Competitions:', 'sntheme' ); ?></label> 
                <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'competitions' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'competitions' ); ?>">
                    <option value="">All Competitions</option>
                        <?php
                        $terms = get_terms("competition");
                        $count = count($terms);
                        if($count > 0) { foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                            if($competitions == $term->term_id) {
                                echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$term->term_id.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<option value="'.$term->term_id.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';
                            }
                          } 
                        } 
                        ?>
                </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'seasons' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Seasons:', 'sntheme' ); ?></label> 
                <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'seasons' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'seasons' ); ?>">
                    <option value="">All Seasons</option>
                <?php
                $terms = get_terms("session");
                $count = count($terms);
                if($count > 0) { foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    if($seasons  == $term->term_id) {
                        echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$term->term_id.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<option value="'.$term->term_id.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';
                    }
                  } 
                 } 
                ?>
                </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('posts_order_by'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Order by:', 'themepixels' ); ?></label>
            <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('posts_order_by'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('posts_order_by'); ?>" class="widefat">
                <option value="meta_value"<?php selected( $instance['posts_order_by'], 'meta_value' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Date', 'themepixels' ); ?></option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_count'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to show:', 'themepixels' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_count'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('post_count'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo intval( $instance['post_count'] ); ?>" />
        </p>

    <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your widget form's foreach loop of both seasons and competitoins, You have used

```
if($competitions == $term->term_id) {......}
```

and

```
if($seasons  == $term->term_id) {.......}
```

But it is wrong, use following codes instead of those:

```
if($instance['competitions'] == $term->term_id) {}
```

and

```
if($instance['seasons  '] == $term->term_id) {}
```